# automate replace of loadsh methods with pure js

Tags: javascript

i need to replace in something like hundred of files the use of _get method,
so lets say i have hunders of files with some lines of code that looks like this:

```
_get(s, 'ex.am.ple', '');
```

which i want to replace to be like this:

```
s?.ex?.amp?.ple || '';
```

is there is some way to automate this proccess somehow with some script?
i am not so familiar with script writing, i writed once some scripts on linux but this is on windows though

Comment: Why not just define your own `_get` instead of replacing all of them? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463)

Comment: I think it's doable with a well written regular expression, i'm not very good at thoose unfortunately

Comment: @coglialoro I wouldn't recommend using a regular expression to parse a programming language source code.